# How to change thumbnail of embedded Youtube video?

Tags: embed, youtube

When I embed a Youtube video onto my page, is there a way to change the thumbnail displayed ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1vSI.jpg))?  I do not have admin access to the Youtube video in-question.

I would prefer a non-plugin solution if possible.  I found [these instructions](http://wpdecoder.com/video-tutorials/custom-thumbnail-with-youtube-video/), but they did not work.

Comment: @Nicolai Thanks for that.  Can you link documentation regarding the `[video]` shortcode?  I'm embedding merely by pasting the Youtube URL onto the page.  Then I allow the WordPress built-in functionality to convert that to the appropriate source code.  I was under the impression it used the `[embed]` shortcode though (but I could be wrong). Regardless, something that allows me to set the thumbnail sounds like what I need.

Comment: OK thanks.  I implemented it, and can indeed change the default thumbnail.  But it comes at a cost of a slightly different video player (screenshot comparison https://imgur.com/a/QVGKL).  The `[video]` shortcode changes the video player to a built-in WordPress player, which  doesn't have the familiar Youtube styling, and is also missing the settings  link and 'watch in Youtube' link (which I like).  Ideally, if possible, I'd like to keep everything about the Youtube player the same except for the thumbnail.  Can I perhaps do so with custom JavaScript?

Comment: OK thanks.  Can we leave this open for a day or two to allow other to read/comment?  I could perhaps be open to a plugin solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`[video]` shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Video_Shortcode) can be used with the `src` being an URL of a youtube video. To set a placeholder, preview thumbnail use `poster`, it even works nicely via GUI. In the end it should look somewhat like the bellow example.

```
[video src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYZ" poster="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/example.jpg"]
```

Comment: I've implemented this (page here http://kabultec.org/blog/events/annual-afghan-womens-benefit-dinner-2017/).  With it, have indeed replaced the thumbnail that is displayed before the video plays.  But when the video finishes playing, it displays the original starting thumbnail--the same starting thumbnail I want to hide (screenshot https://imgur.com/t8N1dPf). Any ideas how to resolve that?  Even a blank, black screen would be a solution in this case.  The motivation for this exercise is to replace or hide this particular thumbnail everywhere on the site.

Comment: Removing `&rel=0` did not do the trick, and I am not the owner of this Youtube channel.  Which `<div>` are you talking about exactly?  I can't find any element with a class of `ytp-cued-thumbnail-overlay` (or similar).

Comment: OK.  I searched the source code for `ytp-cued-thumbnail` but couldn't find it (screenshot:  https://imgur.com/POsfj4r).  Shouldn't it appear there?  Or am I misunderstanding something?  Are you able to send me a screenshot indicating its presence? It's not that I don't believe you, but it might help me figure out where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: OK. That class is added to the page by the Youtube embed, so it was missing from my page, since I switched to the `[video]` shortcode.  But this new solution is a bit more appealing to me--i.e. keep the Youtube embed and change the thumbnail via JavaScript. I've reverted back to the Youtube embed (http://kabultec.org/dev/blog/events/benefit-dinner-2016/) but am having trouble targeting the class.  Specifically, on page load, `document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-cued-thumbnail-overlay-image")[0];` is undefined.  But after I inspect the element, it returns the class in-question. Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe this warrants a separate question to Stack Overflow?

Comment: OK.  Let's keep this question open for a bit longer while I confirm this new solution is viable.  I'll update this question after that research is complete.

Comment: Have all your comments in this thread been deleted?  It appears so on my end.  Anyway, it seems as if I cannot modify that particular class with a server-side JavaScript file (see here https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/7l1cq0/cannot_target_class_unless_i_first_inspect/).  I guess I could try to overlay a separate JPG onto that element with CSS, but that seems relatively fragile.  Unless you see another possible solution/workaround, I'm inclined to mark the `[video]` reply as the answer.

Comment: @cag8f Just cleaning up the noise. I'm not really having another solution. I personally wouldn't even bother with it to begin with, to be honest. It's just not worth the hassle.

Comment: I didn't think they were noise--I thought they were part of a healthy and informative discussion.  But oh well.  I'll mark your `[embed]` reply as the answer.

Comment: @cag8f It's just not how the system here works, it's not like a open forum. I would have let the discussion be in place – or even given another answer –, if it would have contained a proven additional solution. But it didn't, from my side at least. And as the comments get cleaned up sooner or later anyway, I prefer to clean up myself, rather then letting it do other people.

Answer (score 0):

check this out, maybe this will help.

```
<div class="video-responsive"><iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/1Cz2Xzm6knM/videoseries?list=PLq-1Cz2Xzm6knM-1Cz2Xzm6knM&amp;rel=0" width="420" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>


.video-responsive{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    position:relative;
    height:0;
}
.video-responsive iframe{
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```